# When was compulsive hoarding first documented?

Tags: history-of-psychology

When was the first documented of behavior we might recognize today as compulsive hoarding? I've found that the diagnosis was added in ICD-10 and DSM5 and was previously categorized as a subset of OCD. I have also found the case of the [Collyer brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collyer_brothers), whose 1947 death sets the first case at least that far back. I've looked over materials from modern hoarding support charities, but they are focused on how hoarding presents today rather than in years past.

I'm not necessarily looking for the first professional diagnosis if there are older cases documented by amateurs that meet the description of compulsive hoarding. It's okay if the individual is anonymous, but I'm not looking for cases that may be legendary or apocryphal.